# mod_jk on windows 64 bit

Tags: apache, mod-jk

Anyone know where to get a windows 64 bit shared object for mod_jk.  I've just moved to 64 bit machine.  It's not where I would expect to find it: http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/win64/jk-1.2.28/ia64/

Answer (score 0):

I found various binaries for windows here: 
http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/windows/

It worked for me in apache 2.2 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best place to find 64 bit binaries for mod_jk is [Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/). Otherwise, the only way to do this is to download [sources](https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/) and then compile them for 64 bit platform. The instruction is included in readme file. It will point you to native/building.txt with more details on how to achieve this. Here is also a [discussion](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/64bit-windows-mod-jk-connector-download-for-apache-httpd-2-4-td4893904.html) regarding 64bit download for mod_jk that maybe helpful.